# animar cambios encontrados en resultado de ajax angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, animated

Actualmente yo trabajo las inserciones y eliminaciones de registro con `ajax` de la siguiente manera:
1.-  consulto todos los registros que hay y los guardo en `$scope.data`.
2.- Inserto registro en la `base de datos` y ejecuto el paso 1.
3.- Elimino registro en la `BD` y ejecuto el paso 1.

Y en la vista es algo tan simple como:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data">
   {{ item }}
</li>
```

El problema viene cuando utilizo `ng-animate` ya que quiero que tengan animación solo los registros afectados, pero como reasigno todo a la variable `$scope.data` y por eso me anima todos los registros.

Se que puedo usar `push` y `pop` cuando inserte, si se inserta correctamente hago un `push` a `$scope.data` lo mismo con `pop`, pero en el sistema intervienen varias personas por eso me interesa traer todo, ¿existe una mejor manera para hacer esto?

Algo así como "consultar todos los registros y compararlos con mi `varible` `$scope.data` y así ver que se elimino y que se inserto para solo hacer cambio a esos elementos y de esa forma solo me anime los cambios".

Comment: Que has intentado para ver en que esta fallando tu código?, puedes agregar lo que has hecho?